# EF does not crash but no data is being returned to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I just started following Adam Freeman book on `ASP.NET MVC` and building his example.

Here is the code I have so far which is just a list of products that we loop through them and show it in view. That's it.
The problem is I am very new to `EF` and can't figure out why its repo returns no result so my page shows no data.

I really appreciate it if someone can take a quick look and figure out what is going on.

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductsRepository repository;


        public ProductController(IProductsRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }


        public ViewResult List()
        {
            return View(repository.Products);
        }


    }
```

Comment: are you retrive more data like 20,000 data on single request

Comment: @DhavalPatel  oh no, it is a simple step by step example from the book, I have entered only like 7 rows of data

Comment: can you please post some code rather then giving whole solution

Comment: @DhavalPatel no! because I don't know which part of code has issues. Is it Ninject? Is it EF? Is it queries? I don't know. The whole code isn't more than 50 lines really if you careto take a look.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the controller and stepping through to see of anything is getting to the view?

Comment: Step through the debugger like gerdi suggested. Maybe run SQL Server Profiler to verify what query is actually getting run too (if it is in fact running a query).

Comment: @gerdi : As far as my knowledge allowed me I did put a break point in the controller and saw that repository.Products list had zero results.

Comment: I voted to close this question. Questions about why your program isn't working should include the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the code, and it must be in the question itself, not posted as a link to somewhere else.

Comment: @mason I kinda agree, but what if the question included some code and then a link to say github. It might be quite useful in some cases

Comment: @gerdi I'll state again: the question **must** provide the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem, in the question itself. If you want to provide *that* information, plus a link to the complete source code, then that is acceptable. But external links often go down, and that doesn't help the next person that stumbles upon this question that's trying to find a solution (the whole point of Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no data.

I downloaded your project and looked in the Products table and there was nothing there.

You can check this by adding a if statement

```
@if (Model.Any()) { 
  foreach (var p in Model)
  {
   <div class ="item">
     <h3>@p.Name</h3>
     @p.Description
     <h4>@p.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
   </div>
  }
 }
 else
 {
   <h1>No Data!</h1>
 }
```

You can add data by going into the "Server explorer window" ( If you dont have it active you can go into view -> server explorer ) Open to the Products table. Right Click and go "Show table data". Then you can just add it in that table

**Note:** 
I have not downloaded a vs project from github so i am not sure if the .mdf does not work for some reason and you do actually have data. I have gone through the same book though so i do know that it is a localDb thing.

Its not the best book if you are starting out. I would recommend getting "Beginning ASP MVC 4" by apress. The sports store example that he goes through gets very hairy if you are new to all of it. And he only really explains the mechanics of it in subsequent chapters.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes it is the local db, in my machine if I say show data on that table, it lists them but yeah How can  make sure there is not a problem with MDF? If it was good it should have been included in the github source? and How can I make sure EF sees and connects to that local db? It doesn't give me crash or connection error.

Comment: Yeah i did actually get the .mdf .. I think it works 100% , i just wasn't sure. It will give you a yellow screen of death page ( aka yellow cake ) if there is a problem. I was just wondering if maybe the data that you might of had was not brought in when i downloaded it. If that connections string is wrong you it will make sure you know about it.

Comment: Hmm, so you got the mdf and if you right click on its table it shows those 6 or 7 rows of data I have entered? The controller is really just this one line of code in here https://github.com/babakinks/SportsCenter/blob/master/SportsStore.WebUI/Controllers/ProductController.cs

Comment: Well I got the mdf but there was no data. When i added data though i got the list on the page with the data i added

Comment: wow, so it actually did work fine. Weird it didn't show data on the page on my own machine. Thank you SO MUCH for verifying this.